# How to programmatically know whether file/app contain some wheel permissions on mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to know whether some app contains wheel permission or not on mac. As you people can see in **first image wheel permission present**, but in **second image there is no wheel permissions**. I want to write method

```
-(BOOL)isWheelPresent :(NSString *)path
```

Any body can can give me idea how to do this? (using Cocoa & objective-c)

1. iTune.app

[image]

2.iPhoto.app

[image]

Comment: Can you just check to see if the current user has read and/or write permission?

Comment: for iTune.app from terminal ls -l app: drwxr-xr-x+ 9 root  wheel  306 Sep 22  2014 Contents

Comment: Right, but do you need to know the group specifically, or just whether the user has write access to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should just check to see if a file is readable or writable by the current user, using the methods supplied by the `NSFileManager` class. However, if you really do need to know if the `wheel` group owns the file, you can check using the C functions `stat` and `getgrgid` from `sys/stat.h` and `grp.h`. Here is a sample Objective-C class that wraps the C code behind a method, along with a simple program that exits with 0 if `wheel` owns the file, and 1 if it does not:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

@interface FileOwnerManager : NSObject
- (BOOL)isWheelPresent:(NSString *)path;
@end

@implementation FileOwnerManager

- (BOOL)isWheelPresent:(NSString *)path
{
    struct stat f_stat;
    int res = stat([path UTF8String], &f_stat);
    if (res != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
        return NO;
    }
    struct group *group = getgrgid(f_stat.st_gid);
    NSLog(@"%@: %s", path, group->gr_name);
    return strcmp(group->gr_name, "wheel") == 0;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BOOL res = NO;
    @autoreleasepool {
        FileOwnerManager *fom = [[FileOwnerManager alloc] init];
        res = [fom isWheelPresent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]]];
        [fom release];
    }
    return res ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: You should always use `-[NSFileManager stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:length:]` and `-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]` when dealing with strings from or for BSD/POSIX-land which are intended to be file paths, not UTF-8-centric APIs. Also, this only deals with traditional group and permission flags, but "wheel" can appear in that Get Info window due to ACLs, too. Otherwise, +1.